# is there any way to add values from all tag, which are inside a specific tag in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

is there any way to add values from all tag, which are inside a specific tag in XSLT?. I know XSLT is 
for transforming tag, however, i thinks, there should be a way to do that

```
<main>
  <front>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
  <d>4</d>
  <e>5</e>
  <f>6</f>
  <g>7</g>
  <h>8</h>

  </front>
<back>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
</back>
<main>
```

Preferred output:
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 36

I tried this way, but not working.

```
<xsl:template match="front">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="sum(*)"/>` to sum up the child elements.